# react-country-region-selector component given error Text string must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have copy code from npm. Below code show, given error Text string must be rendered within a  component.
How we can removed this error.
I make a component and used this code. But not working i try some style css but not working.

````
// note that you can also export the source data via CountryRegionData. It's in a deliberately concise format to 
// keep file size down
import { CountryDropdown, RegionDropdown, CountryRegionData } from 'react-country-region-selector';


class Example extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { country: '', region: '' };
  }

  selectCountry (val) {
    this.setState({ country: val });
  }

  selectRegion (val) {
    this.setState({ region: val });
  }

  render () {
    const { country, region } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <CountryDropdown
          value={country}
          onChange={(val) => this.selectCountry(val)} />
        <RegionDropdown
          country={country}
          value={region}
          onChange={(val) => this.selectRegion(val)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Generally this issue arise when you have some text inside  a JSX  which is outside a Text component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-country-region-selector` is a library made for React (on the web), not React Native. It includes HTML markup, which is not supported by React Native.

The reason for this exact error message is because `<div>` is recognised as a text string (not HTML tag, not a component), and since it's not rendered within a `<Text>` component you get this specific error.